# Android Custom Keyboard appears half

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-keyboard

The keyboard was appearing full but for some reasons, the last two rows are hidden. I tried to change keyboard height from XML but it didn't help.

[image]

**Keyboard Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="10px">
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="q"
            android:popupCharacters="1"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="w"
            android:popupCharacters="2"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="e"
            android:popupCharacters="3ëèéê"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="r"
            android:popupCharacters="4"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="t"
            android:popupCharacters="5"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="y"
            android:popupCharacters="6"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="u"
            android:popupCharacters="7úùûū"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="i"
            android:popupCharacters="8"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="o"
            android:popupCharacters="9œôóō"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="p"
            android:popupCharacters="0"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key
            android:horizontalGap="4%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="a"
            android:popupCharacters="æáãäāȁȃå"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="s"
            android:popupCharacters="ϐ"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="d" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="f" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="g" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="h" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="j" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="k" />
        <Key
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="l" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="-1"
            android:isModifier="true"
            android:isSticky="true"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_shift_24dp"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="z" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="x" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="c"
            android:popupCharacters="ç"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="v" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="b" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="n"
            android:popupCharacters="ñ"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="m" />
        <Key
            android:codes="-5"
            android:isRepeatable="true"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_backspace_24dp"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" />
    </Row>

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key
            android:codes="-2"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="\?123"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="-10000"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_insert_emoticon_24dp" />
        <!--
            android:codes: -101 is not a framework-defined key code but a key code that is
            privately defined in com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView.
        -->
        <Key
            android:codes="-101"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_language_24dp" />
        <Key
            android:codes="32"
            android:isRepeatable="true"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_space_24dp"
            android:keyWidth="35%p" />
        <Key
            android:keyLabel="."
            android:keyWidth="15%p"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_symbols" />
        <Key
            android:codes="10"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_next_circle_filled_24dp"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking the log, I found the following error:

> E/Keyboard: Parse
> error:android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
> res/drawable/ic_backspace_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f0703ae

I replaced the file and everything came to normal.